# How to effectively extract emails with attachments from Gmail and present them sequentially?

Tags: email, pdf, gmail

I'm working on a legal case and I need to forward a set of emails of evidential value to my lawyers.

There are roughly 50 such emails from various conversations, and some of them have between 1-10 attachments. Some of the attachments are images, some are PDFs, and some attachments are emails (some of which contain image attachments).

How can I possibly extract all of this into some sort of human-readable form? My best idea so far is a word document in which I copy & paste everything sequentially.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a Thunderbird client to load the mails (IMAP) and use [this extension](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/attachmentextractor-continued/) to extract the attachments.

To create a single document with all the info (text from emails, images, pdfs etc.) your best bet is probably either Adobe Acrobat or a tool like [PDF Creator](https://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator). You might have to save the text from the emails in files manually and individually before trying to use these tools.

For data of this kind you'll probably not avoid some manual work sorting the files.